# JBoss servers with loadbalancer

Tags: java, jboss, load-balancing

I have a webservice, which run on few JBoss servers.

The configuration looks like this:

```
Apache (as Load Balancer) -> (n instances of) Jboss
```

I wounder if i realy need Apache as LB. I found, that JBosses servers can work in Channel.
But i'm not sure it it means, that channel can work as LB and if i send request from Apache to server 1 from Channel, JBoss server will distribute this request to server with less load ?

If not, then what the Channel means ?

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss the communication between the nodes is handled by the **JGroups** group communication library, with a **JGroups** `Channel` providing the core functionality of tracking who is in the cluster and reliably exchanging messages between the cluster members. **JGroups** channels with the same configuration and name have the ability to dynamically discover each other and form a group.

**E.g.** a channel used by a distributed `HttpSession` cache or `EJB3` cache.

In **HTTP-based JBoss services**, an external load balancer is required to process all requests and dispatch them to server nodes in the cluster.  The load balancer is logically part of the cluster, but we refer to it as “external” because it is not running in the same process as either the client or any of the JBoss AS instances. It can be implemented in software (mod_jk, mod_cluster, etc).

**REF:** http://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/html/clustering-blocks.chapt.html